# How can i create an alert dialog to prompt user for username and password after a radio button has been clicked (Android)?

Tags: android

How can i create an alert dialog to prompt user for username and password after a radio button has been clicked and uncheck the radio button if the alert dialog was cancelled without imputing the values . (android).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudocode for your problem. Hope it helps :

```
 RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                /**
                 * If checkedId is the Id of your radio button then write 
                 * the code to show dialog to take username and password as 
                 * input. If canceled then call radioGroup.clearCheck()
                 */

            }
        });
```